# NaN and Infinity values in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I am using Visual Studio to build my report and I have tried to use those three expressions:

```
=IIF(Fields!A.Value = 0 or Fields!B.Value = 0, 0,SUM(Fields!A.Value)/SUM(Fields!A.Value)

=IIF(SUM(Fields!A.Value) = 0 or SUM(Fields!B.Value =0),0,SUM(Fields!A.Value)/SUM(Fields!A.Value)

=Replace(Round((((SUM(Fields!A.Value)/SUM(Fields!B.Value)))*100),0),"NaN","0")+"%"
```

The first 2 give me only 0 as % and the last one doesnt get rid of Infinity but does get rid of NaN.

Can someone please help where I can use both these expressions together and not get only 0% and Infinity when I use either the top 2 or the last one?

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data, and your expected outcomes for those respective samples?

Answer (score 9):

At first, you need to be sure that the fields you are using to calculate your value are really numbers.

Normally, you get `NaN` when trying to divide 0 / 0 or `Infinity` when you are dividing any number by 0.

So, a **generic resolution** for `NaN`, `Infinity` or even `#Error` (that happens when a null value is passed to a division) is to create a Function that will work on this values for you.

Right click on the background of your report and go to Report Properties as shown:

[image: Accessing Report Properties on BID 2008]

Then you can go on tab `Code` and add your custom code:

```
Public Function Divide(ByVal dividend As Double, ByVal divisor As Double) As Double
   If IsNothing(divisor) Or divisor = 0 Or IsNothing(dividend) Or dividend = 0 Then
      Return 0
   Else
      Return dividend / divisor
   End If
End Function
```

We use `IsNothing()` to avoid `#Error` and check whether the divisor or the dividend are 0 to avoid `NaN` and `Infinity`.

And then you replace your expression with:

```
= Code.Divide(Sum(Fields!A.Value), Sum(Fields!B.Value))
```

To make this looks like a percentage, I strongly recommend you change your `Textbox` properties. So, right click on it, go on Textbox Properties and over tab Number. Select category Percentage.

By doing this, you make sure that de SSRS will consider this value as **percentage and not a text** even when it is exported to other platforms such as Excel.

You can also check the [Microsoft documentation on adding code to a Report (SSRS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156028.aspx)

Comment: It is also useful when you need to put `0` instead of `null` values, that would appear in blank on SSRS. you can use `Code.Divide(<<Expr>>, 1)` so if your Expression is `null`, it returns 0, otherwise it returns the value of the expression itself.

Comment: Is there a way to return NULL instead of 0?  I have a complex expression on a Matrix table and I am trying to return NULL.  However, I keep receiving either NaN or 0 no matter what I try.

Comment: have you tried to change the Divide function to return `Null` instead of 0? are you trying to divide two numbers?

Comment: This really helped me and is the most useful response I have seen anywhere regarding Nan and Infinity results.

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting 0% and NaN I'd check check your field data types. You should have at least one non-integer, and both need to be numeric. I'd still expect to see some 1s, but this is a start at the 0% and NaN. In terms of your check, you only need to check the denominator to avoid a calculation error.
Try:

```
=IIF(Sum(Fields!B.Value) <> 0 , Sum(Fields!A.Value) / Sum(Fields!B.Value), 0 )
```

Control your presentation (decimal places, % sign etc.) with the textbox Format properties, or the equation number properties.